# GUICE: Inject value dependent on scope

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have a Controller class.

This class needs a different enum value, depending on where it is injected. I do not want to create subclasses for the controller.

How can I do this?

Example:

```
class FirstItem {

    //some of these have an injected controller which needs the enum value 'FIRST'
    @Inject
    @FirstSubItems //Custom annotation for multibinding
    Set<Item> subItems;
}

class SecondItem {

    //some of these have an injected controller which needs the enum value 'SECOND'
    @Inject
    @SecondSubItems //Custom annotation for multibinding
    Set<Item> subItems;
}

class Controller {
    @Inject
    MyEnum enumValue;
}
```

Can this be done elegantly? How would I configure the module?

The module looks like this currently:

```
Multibinder<Item> toolsSectionOne = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder, Item.class, FirstSubItems.class);
toolsSectionOne.addBinding().to(Item1.class);
toolsSectionOne.addBinding().to(Item2.class);

Multibinder<Item> toolsSectionTwo = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder, Item.class, SecondSubItems.class);
toolsSectionTwo.addBinding().to(Item1.class);
toolsSectionTwo.addBinding().to(Item2.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with a PrivateBinder:

```
Type type = TypeLiteral.get(Item.class).getType();
Type setType = Types.setOf(type);

PrivateBinder privateBinderOne = binder.newPrivateBinder();
privateBinderOne.bind(MyEnum.class).toInstance(MyEnum.FIRST);
Multibinder<Item> toolsSectionOne = Multibinder.newSetBinder(privateBinderOne , Item.class, FirstSubItems.class);
toolsSectionOne.addBinding().to(Item1.class);
toolsSectionOne.addBinding().to(Item2.class);
privateBinderOne.expose(Key.get(setType, FirstSubItems.class));

PrivateBinder privateBinderTwo = binder.newPrivateBinder();
privateBinderTwo.bind(MyEnum.class).toInstance(MyEnum.SECOND);
Multibinder<Item> toolsSectionTwo = Multibinder.newSetBinder(privateBinderTwo , Item.class, SecondSubItems.class);
toolsSectionTwo.addBinding().to(Item1.class);
toolsSectionTwo.addBinding().to(Item2.class);
privateBinderTwo.expose(Key.get(setType, SecondSubItems.class));
```

This works like a charm.

Comment: Could you post up the classes that use this?  I need to do something similar and can't see how you're injecting these.

Comment: Like stated in the question (first code snippet). As they are annotated multibindings I Inject them via the annotation. In a constructor it would look like this: @Inject public FirstItem(@FirstSubItems Set<Item>). Does that help you? It's basically about creating submodules with customized configurations within a module.

Comment: Also tom, you don't need the type magic if you are dealing with ordinary types without multibinding. The call to expose then becomes simple.